# Raspberry pi: Inconsistency detected, assertion failed

Tags: raspbian, raspi-config, update

I get the below error when I do: sudo apt-get upgrade

Please help:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
bind9-host cups-bsd cups-client cups-common firmware-realtek fuse hostscript libbind9-80 libcups2 libcupsimage2 libdns88 libexpat1 libfuse2  libgs9 libgs9-common libicu48 libisc84 libisccc80 libisccfg82 liblwres80 libnss3 libraspberrypi-bin libraspberrypi-dev libraspberrypi-doc   libraspberrypi0 libsdl1.2debian libsqlite3-0 libssl1.0.0 openssl raspberrypi-bootloader raspi-config sonic-pi
```

32 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/121 MB of archives.
After this operation, 6,769 kB of additional disk space will be used.

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%

Preconfiguring packages ...

Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dynamic-link.h: 190: elf_get_dynamic_info: Assertion `info[20]->d_un.d_val == 17 || info[20]->d_un.d_val == 7' failed!

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (127)
```

Comment: Can you paste a few lines before that error as well

Comment: Also have a look at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=95263

Comment: Did not help, updating question with a few more lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm this is caused by defective Micro/SD Card or corrupted file system. The solution that work for me is just replace your card with the new one.

Comment: No guarantee the SD card is the problem